# InAppBilling app is closing and gets destroyed after purchase window is closed without error

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

After the purchase window is closed, my app is closing aswell. There is no error or crash, it is just finishing. What could be the reason? I have implemented the purchase functionality in the same activity in which the user can select items to buy.

Edit:

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

I have used this library and did it exactly the same way as it is shown on the link.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (bp != null){ 
        bp.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to put some code up in order to get help. Can you add the code where the logic for the purchase completion is?

Comment: Maybe i should mention that i am doing the purchase call in an AlertDialog with multiple items, from which one can be selected.

bp.purchase(item_id);

Comment: FOR ANYONE who faces the same issue.
I´ve solved it. The problem was that i had set the flag of the new intent which is leading to the shop to .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Don´t do that. I can´t tell you why this is a problem, but since i deleted this line, everything is working fine.

Comment: And if you decide to use the same library you will probably get an OnBillingError:102. Just call the bp.purchase(product_id) command again in the OnBillingError Method.

Comment: if you have a solution, you can answer the question yourself and accept the answer

Comment: No i can´t due to low reputation.